# How do you sort an Array of Comments and Sub-comment Objects by id and likes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, filter

I am working on a forum and after retrieving all comments for a post, I am trying to sort them into comments and sub-comments.

Each comment has its own unique ID as well as the ID of its parent. In cases were the comment is made directly on the post (ie. top level comment) the parent ID equals the forum post ID.

```
"doc": [{
        "id": "73emgNKLiCdzcREyCLtg",
        "data": {
                  "likeCount": 0,
                  "body": "comment text",
                  "createdAt": "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z",
                  "forumPostId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr",        //forumPostID is same as ParentId
                  "parentId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr"
                }
        }, {
        "id": "2sRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr",
        "data": {
                  "likeCount": 0,
                  "body": "subcomment text",
                  "createdAt": "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z",
                  "forumPostId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr",
                  "parentId": "73emgNKLiCdzcREyCLtg"
                }
        }, {
        "id": "1242sR1qDqSeLqXv3mAr",
        "data": {
                  "likeCount": 1,
                  "body": "subcomment text",
                  "createdAt": "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z",
                  "forumPostId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr",       //forumPostID is same as ParentId
                  "parentId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr"
                }
        }, {...
```

I am trying to store the sorted comments in an object called "comments." Each generation of comments and sub-comments is sorted based on "likeCount" and "CreatedAt", and each comment contains all of its sub-comments. The final result would look something like this:

```
"comments": [{
            "id": "1242sR1qDqSeLqXv3mAr",
            "data": {
                      "likeCount": 1,                          //comment with most likes moved to top
                      "body": "subcomment text",
                      "createdAt": "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z",
                      "forumPostId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr",
                      "parentId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr"
                    },
            "comments": {}
            }, {
            "id": "73emgNKLiCdzcREyCLtg",
            "data": {
                      "likeCount": 0,
                      "body": "comment text",
                      "createdAt": "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z",
                      "forumPostId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr",
                      "parentId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr"
                    },
            "comments": {
                      "id": "2sRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr",
                      "data": {
                                "likeCount": 0,
                                "body": "subcomment text",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z",
                                "forumPostId": "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr",
                                "parentId": "73emgNKLiCdzcREyCLtg"
                              }
                      }
            }, {...
```

*Note that sub-comments can have sub-comments (ie. there can by infinite generations)

I have been reading up on find(), filter() and sort() but can't wrap my head around exactly what a function/loop to accomplish this would look like.

Any and all help/guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why do you want to do this on the client and not on the server?

Comment: I think you meant `comments` should be an array of comment objects, not an object itself, right?

Comment: I guess you are keeping the data on a database, won't it be better if you changed your query and got the data structure you need from there?

Comment: @Andreas sorry for any confusion, I am doing this server side. the sorted object will be forwarded to the client

Comment: @AmitB. correct

Comment: @ArootinAghazaryan I am charged per pull, so i figured it would be more efficient to pull all comments with forumPostID = to the post then sort them on the server (cloud function for firebase) then forward them to the client via an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I added an "order by likes" parameter to the database query then I used a forEach loop to cycle through all the raw comment data and push comments with PrentIds = to the comment-in-question's ID to its comment array. It's not the prettiest function in the world but here is the result:

```
.
.
.
.then((data) => {
      forumPostData.comments = [];
      buildComments(forumPostData, data);
      return res.json(forumPostData);
    })
.
.
.

      function buildComments(object, data) {
          data.forEach((doc) => {
            if (doc.data().parentId === object.id) {
              let comm = {
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data(),
                comments: []
              };
              object.comments.push(comm);
              let index = object.comments.findIndex(x => x.id === doc.id);
              buildComments(object.comments[index], data);
            }
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the items as a tree and sort the items.

```js
var data = [{ id: "73emgNKLiCdzcREyCLtg", data: { likeCount: 0, body: "comment text", createdAt: "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z", forumPostId: "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr", parentId: "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr" } }, { id: "2sRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr", data: { likeCount: 0, body: "subcomment text", createdAt: "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z", forumPostId: "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr", parentId: "73emgNKLiCdzcREyCLtg" } }, { id: "1242sR1qDqSeLqXv3mAr", data: { likeCount: 1, body: "subcomment text", createdAt: "2020-01-16T21:42:37.782Z", forumPostId: "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr", parentId: "csRvt21qDqSeLqXv3mAr" } }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            t[o.data.parentId] = t[o.data.parentId] || {};
            t[o.data.parentId].children = t[o.data.parentId].children || [];
            t[o.data.parentId].children.push(t[o.id]);
            t[o.data.parentId].children.sort((a, b) => b.data.likeCount - a.data.likeCount);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, data[0].data.forumPostId);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```